# Add class to an element within an HTML Application from within VBS function

Tags: css, dom, vbscript, hta

I have an HTA that is displayed when a backup routine is complete and I'd like to be able to manipulate the HTA via VBS, showing whether or not a series of folders were backed up correctly.

So, using the ID of an element within the HTA, is it possible to add a class to the element?

For example -

> If result = true Then {add class 'success' to id 'result-documents'}

Here is my VBS for showing the HTA -

```
Shell.Run COMPLETED_MESSAGE_PATH, 0, True
```

And example of an element that I wish to target is as below.  For example, here I'd like to add a class attribute (the class name varies) to the element with ID 'result-documents' -

```
<span class="list-item"><span id="result-documents"></span>Documents</span>
```

Comment: Do I want to know why you use a VBSCript to launch an Internet Explorer to push HTA code into that Internet Explorer instead of just using an HTA in the first place?

Comment: I'm new to the wonders of HTA, so my code is far from perfect.  Opening the HTA directly works, but in the context of my solution I'm not yet sure how I'd do things lkie size/position the window, pause the srcipt until the user closes the HTA and indeed interact with it.  Suggestions and links to resources are always welcome :)

Comment: For an introdution to HTAs have a [look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [at](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) [these](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692769.aspx).

Comment: Cheers, I will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element in question doesn't have a `class` attribute already you need to create one first before you can assign a value to it:

```
Set p = IE.Document.getElementById("result-documents")

Set attr = IE.Document.createAttribute("class")
attr.value = "success"
p.setAttributeNode(attr)
```

For running this code directly in an HTA just remove the IE object, because IE already is your runtime environment in that context:

```
Set p = document.getElementById("result-documents")

Set attr = document.createAttribute("class")
attr.value = "success"
p.setAttributeNode(attr)
```

If your element ID didn't have a hyphen in it (e.g. `resultsDocuments` instead of `results-documents`) you could even use its ID directly:

```
Set attr = document.createAttribute("class")
attr.value = "success"
resultDocuments.setAttributeNode(attr)
```

Comment: I've made a big change to my code (question is updated) and am now executing the HTA directly, as opposed to stripping out it's code and showing it in IE (as you suggested).  If you could take another look and let me know if what I am trying is possible I'd be most greatful.

Comment: Just to confirm, I'm doing this from my VBS script, not from within the HTA?  Basically I have a two dimensional array in my VBS - `( ( {element ID}, {result} ), ... )` - and so I'm looping through the array and I need to set `attr.value` to either "success" or "fail" depending on the corrisponding result.  However, using your code as above is yeilding the error `Variable is undefined 'document'`. Thanks.

Comment: You put your VBScript code *inside* the HTA (as the A in HTA). I'll post links to an HTA introduction later today.

Comment: I've been having a play and have migrated my code over to an HTA.  My main issue was that I had two separate HTA's, launched depending upon some login with my VBS script.  I've had to combine them both in to one, which was a pain to be honest, but it's done now and my original query is now solved. Thanks for the help.